# unhandled promise rejection warning (despite having catch block)

Tags: node.js, bluebird

I seem to have a chained catch block for handling promise rejection (and it does catch the rejection ok) but I still see the warning about unhandled promise rejection. What am I not getting right here?

```
Promise.resolve(req.query.request_token)
.then(function(rt) {
  request_token = rt+'2'
  return kc.generateSession(request_token, api_secret)
})
.then(function(resp) {
  console.log(resp)
  return kc.setAccessToken(resp.access_token)
})
.then(() => console.log(kc))
.catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Comment: What exactly is getting rejected? Can you post a [MCVE]?

Comment: If you're getting the `.catch()`, then your warning is probably coming from somewhere else.  You need to track the error and see where it's actually coming from.

Answer (score 0):

So, I tried recreating this example and seeing if something is wrong with your promise chain, but I don't think there is because my below example works fine, ie: I tried throwing errors, and rejecting each one of the mock functions but no matter what I do in the mock functions, the 'this happens here' still gets printed.

```
function testResolve() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => res(1))
}

function generateSession(a, b) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    console.log(a)
    console.log(b)
    res(`a: ${a}, b: ${b}`)
  })
}

function setAccessToken(token) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    res(1)
  })
}

Promise.resolve(testResolve())
.then(function(rt) {
  var request_token = rt+'2'
  return generateSession(request_token, 'a1')
})
.then(function(resp) {
  console.log(resp)
  return setAccessToken(resp.access_token)
})
.then(() => console.log(x))
.catch(err => {
  console.log('this happens here')
  console.error(err)
})
```

I would check the unhandled promise rejection message and see the line number that it gives you, and look at the filename where the error occurred. It's possible that there was an unhandled rejection inside code somewhere else, because as far as I know this promise chain should catch any errors that happen anywhere in the chain.